# Is A intersection B equal to ø if it's probability is zero?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

My textbook includes this question:

If $A$ and $B$ are events such that $P(A|B) = P(B|A)$, then

$(A) A \subset B$ but $A \neq B$

$(B) A = B$

$(C) A \cap B = \emptyset$

$(D) P(A) = P(B)$

The answer key states only option $(D)$ as the answer. Is option $(C)$ also correct since if $A \cap B = \emptyset$, then $P(A \cap B) = P(\emptyset) = 0$ and putting that into the conditional probability formula makes both sides $P(A|B) = P(B|A) = 0$?
Please comment.
Thank you

Comment: Yes your method is correct also

Comment: $A\cap B=\emptyset$ implies $P(A|B)=P(B|A)$, however $P(A|B)=P(B|A)$ does not imply that $A\cap B$ must be empty, and that is what the question is asking. So it is not correct to select C.

Comment: In the title, the formulation is the other way round and not true in general (probability $0$ does not mean that the event is impossible).

Comment: D is also a wrong answer, by the way.

Comment: Consider $X \sim N(0,1)$.  Then $P((X\le 0)\cup(X \ge 0))= 0$ since the intersection (the possible event $X=0$ so not empty) has zero probability.

Comment: $P(A\mid B)=P(B\mid A)$ implies that either (a) both are $0$ though this does not require their intersection is empty just having zero probability, or (b) $P(A)=P(B)$   which gives a lot of freedom over their intersection - anything from empty to the whole of $A$ and $B$

Comment: What @MichalAdamaszek commented.  For a specific example: let $A = [0,1]$ and let $B = [1,2].$  Then $A \cap B = \{1\}.$  Now consider choosing an element at random from the set $[0,2]$.  The probability of choosing the element in $A \cap B$ is $0$, but (despite this), $A \cap B$ is not equal to the empty set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I believe the book is incorrect and there is not enough information to answer this question adequately.**

We are told $A$ and $B$ are events such that $P(A|B) = P(B|A)$, and this is the only assumption we are allowed to make. Under this assumption, we know

$$\frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)} = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(A)}$$

by definition of conditional probability. This statement holds whether $A$ and $B$ are disjoint, so we do not know whether $A$ and $B$ are disjoint. In other words, we do not know if $A \cap B = \emptyset$.

If $A$ and $B$ are not disjoint with $P(A \cap B) > 0$, then division by $P(A \cap B)$ is defined and we can derive $P(A) = P(B)$ as follows

$ \frac{1}{P(A \cap B)} \cdot \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)} = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(A)} \cdot \frac{1}{P(A \cap B)}$

$\Leftrightarrow \frac{1}{P(B)} = \frac{1}{P(A)}$

$\Leftrightarrow P(A)P(B) \cdot \frac{1}{P(B)} = \frac{1}{P(A)} \cdot P(A)P(B)$

$\Leftrightarrow P(A) = P(B)$

But if $A$ and $B$ are disjoint with $P(A \cap B) = P(\emptyset) = 0$, then division by $P(A \cap B)$ is *not defined* and $P(A) = P(B)$ is not necessarily true. For instance, imagine we flip a biased coin with events $H$ and $T$ for heads and tails, respectively. Of course, $H \cap T = \emptyset$, so we have $P(H|T) = P(T|H) = 0$, and since the coin is biased, we have $P(H) \neq P(T)$. However, if the coin is fair, then $P(H|T) = P(T|H) = 0$ and $P(H) = P(T)$.

Hence, $(C)$ cannot be an answer because we are not told whether $A$ and $B$ are disjoint and this is not implied by the information given. And $(D)$ cannot be an answer because it depends on whether $A$ and $B$ are disjoint.